# Finding a maximum value in a dataseries using Prometheus or Grafana

Tags: dashboard, metrics, grafana, prometheus

We use the wmi_exporter to scrape system metrics from a Windows server. Now we want to find out the time periods where this server was used more than a certain percentage / amount.

In our Grafana dashboard I can see that on a certain day there was a spike:
[image: Spike on October 20th]

But it is not possible to find this specific day when looking at for example 10 days:
[image: Maximum missing]

It seems like this value is levelled out. My original plan was to check each month for spikes and then drill down to the specific days. But this won't work because I would miss spikes.

How can I find those spikes without inspecting every single day ?